# specifying section id manually while saving section

Tags: craft3

Is is possible to set the "section id" manually by using

`Craft::$app->sections->saveSection($section);`?

Can we specify the id of a section in an `$section` array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Craft will throw an exception when you insert an id that does not exist into the form. Is there a certain reason for your question? Maybe we could provide help on that.

Comment: i am trying to import content from api and insert to section[channel type], i am trying to insert id because it will be easy for me to find whether the content that i received from api already exist in my entires or not. if yes then i will just update the content rather than creating duplicate. It will work some how exactly like FeedMe plugin for craft 2.

Comment: The better approach would be to fetch to fetch the section by handle `$section = Craft::$app->getSections()->getSectionByHandle('yourHandle');` if it returns `null` you'll create a new section if not you'll work with that